# What is causing this .git folder with files called .git_high_size?

Tags: git

I deleted a large .git folder in the root html directory, as I wasn't using .git and it must have been a carry over from a server move. Now, a directory called `.git_high size` has created itself and is filled with other folders and files. There is a space between `high` and `size` and in SSH I can't `cd` to it.

The files are filled with i.e.,  `xÌ}ks«ëÌ˝zı+∞¸B…óÇÎ˝ê√ÊRÿ5C&©ª±6p?W∏¢ôm+¸Ô7@ìU’’‰LıLcê......'

What is causing this? Is git still running?

This is CentOS 7.9.2009.

```
whereis git
git: /usr/bin/git /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin/git /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
```

**FTP screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You deleted the `.git` folder in a checked out repository? Did you then try to use `git` commands? Where is this directory located in relation to your (now defunct) Git repository?

Comment: I didn't try and use git; did someone else? The site owner didn't. Does that mean someone else has server access?

Comment: How exactly did you delete the directory? Via FTP? What FTP server is running on the system? The directories and files look like the normal contents in the `.git` directory. Maybe it has not been deleted but renamed to implement a trashcan mechanism.

Comment: The site owner deleted it via FTP. The server is running Pure-FTPd.

Comment: Edited question: There is a space between `high` and `size` and in SSH I can't `cd` to the `.git_high` directory: `No such file or directory`.

Comment: As Bodo said previous, it looks like the `.git` directory got renamed into `.git_high size`. You may want to clarify with the site owner what they actually did (things like these don't happen "by themselves") and what they want to do with these files (which are likely internal Git repository files).

Comment: Try: cd “.git_high size” to cd into it.

Comment: Thanks, someone else still using git appeared to be what was happening. Should I delete this question?